# Issue with idle connections/open transactions from Python to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, python

I am having issue with Python code leaving idle connections to SQL Server while having open transactions in them.

Background

Recently, we had some major blockings on the SQL Server database due to Python connections.  The login used has read-only access to SQL Server.  The Python users are performing only reads on the database so they do not necessarily need to open transaction.  However, it seems there is some default setting in Python that creates the open transaction.  While users tend to leave their connections open, so we end up having resources locked sometimes from these idle connections.

Question:
I manage SQL Server database and developers own Python code.  Need suggestion on how developers can change their settings in Python to avoid transactions for read-only queries.  One of the solution I have is to kill their connections when a particular job needs to run so as to avoid blocking but I do not prefer this approach.

Comment: There must be a way in Python to not start a new transaction when a connection is established to the database. That might be more of a question for [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) though. If you have any documentation you can link to regarding Python's *default* behavior on opening a new transaction with every connection, you should add it to your post. Also it's generally best practice to not keep connections open longer than they're needed (one unit of work) so the applications should be closing their connections automatically after they finish executing the query.

Comment: One cannot _not_ open a transaction; it may be explicit or implicit, automatically committed or not, but every SQL statement is always in a transaction.

Comment: I agree with @J.D. this question is better suited for SO since it's about client programming, specifically python. Consider discussing your observations with the developers if you haven't already done as that might help them discover the error in their ways.

Comment: I expect there's some setting for "implicit transactions" in your python that you need to toggle in the other direction. But like others said, this feels like a Python question.

Answer (score 1):

The driver used for the database connection should have connection settings that govern transaction behavior. The pyodbc driver for python, for example, has the “autocommit” setting. With autocommit set to “True”, the SQL Server session will autocommit transactions - each statement that opens a transaction will autocommit that transaction as it completes.
Using the pyodbc driver, if autocommit is set to “False” the session will have implicit_transactions ON. A number of statements implicitly begin a transaction (unless the session is already within a transaction) in this mode. Note that some SELECT statements may avoid starting a transaction if they do not specify a table. Implicit transactions do not commit automatically when the statement which began them completes. Implicit transactions require a commit or rollback.
More information about pyodbc here - but if using a different driver look for that driver’s documentation.
[pyodbc Database Transaction Management](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management)

More information about implicit transactions here…
[implicit_transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)